# AbsoluteLayout controls on a modal page only position horizontally in .NET MAUI

Tags: xaml, maui, absolutelayout

Is there any way to position an AbsoluteLayout control on the center of the screen, or at least on the center of the page as an overlay, on a modal page? Is this possible in any way or why does this not work as expected? Using MAUI Community Toolkit I could create a Popup as an overlay but this obviously has a lot of limitations!

Here's my example page:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp1.ModalPage"
             Shell.PresentationMode="ModalAnimated"
             BackgroundColor="#55000000">
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="End">
        <Frame Style="{StaticResource PopupFrameModal}"
               StyleClass="PopupFrame"
               BackgroundColor="White"
               BorderColor="White"
               HeightRequest="256"
               Margin="0,0,0,-24" CornerRadius="24">
            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center">
                    <BoxView HeightRequest="10" WidthRequest="100" CornerRadius="5"/>
                    <BoxView HeightRequest="1" Margin="0,18,0,24"/>
                    <VerticalStackLayout>
                        <Label Text="This is a modal page" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                    </VerticalStackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
                <AbsoluteLayout>
                    <ActivityIndicator AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                                       AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5"
                                       Margin="0,16,0,0"
                                       IsVisible="True"
                                       IsRunning="True"/>
                </AbsoluteLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
        <!-- Could also be placed here, but 
             the indicator will show up below 
             the modal page instead... -->
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

In this example the control that I used a simple `<ActivityIndicator>` for the `<AbsoluteLayout>`. It could be anything more complex. The indicator only centers horizontally. Vertically it behaves like a relatively positioned control, also when setting properties such as margins. Notice the `Shell.PresentationMode="ModalAnimated"` prop that I used for the `<ContentPage>`.

Comment: Note: This is not a problem with the page being modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your *AbsoluteLayout* is a **child** of a *StackLayout*, then it won't necessarily be in the center of the *ContentPage*, because you're telling it to be **stacked vertically** below other visual elements.

If you want the *AbsoluteLayout* to overlay everything else, it should not be a child of the *StackLayout*, but instead it should be on the same hierarchical level as the *StackLayout* but with a higher z-index.

You could achieve this, for example, by wrapping the *StackLayout* and the *AbsoluteLayout* in a [Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/grid), which is commonly used for stacking in z-direction:

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp1.ModalPage"
             Shell.PresentationMode="ModalAnimated"
             BackgroundColor="#55000000">
    <Grid>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="End">
            <Frame Style="{StaticResource PopupFrameModal}"
                   StyleClass="PopupFrame"
                   BackgroundColor="White"
                   BorderColor="White"
                   HeightRequest="256"
                   Margin="0,0,0,-24" CornerRadius="24">
                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center">
                    <BoxView HeightRequest="10" WidthRequest="100" CornerRadius="5"/>
                    <BoxView HeightRequest="1" Margin="0,18,0,24"/>
                    <VerticalStackLayout>
                        <Label Text="This is a modal page" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                    </VerticalStackLayout>
                </StackLayout>                
            </Frame>
        </StackLayout>
        <AbsoluteLayout VerticalOptions="Fill"
                        HorizontalOptions="Fill">
            <ActivityIndicator AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                               AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5"
                               Margin="0,16,0,0"
                               IsVisible="True"
                               IsRunning="True"/>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </Grid>    
</ContentPage>
```

However, this shouldn't even be necessary. For the purpose of showing an *ActivityIndicator* in the center of the page, you can simply place the *ActivityIndicator* directly into the center of the *Grid*, on top of the *StackLayout* (in z-direction) like this:

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp1.ModalPage"
             Shell.PresentationMode="ModalAnimated"
             BackgroundColor="#55000000">
    <Grid>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="End">
            <Frame Style="{StaticResource PopupFrameModal}"
                   StyleClass="PopupFrame"
                   BackgroundColor="White"
                   BorderColor="White"
                   HeightRequest="256"
                   Margin="0,0,0,-24" CornerRadius="24">
                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center">
                    <BoxView HeightRequest="10" WidthRequest="100" CornerRadius="5"/>
                    <BoxView HeightRequest="1" Margin="0,18,0,24"/>
                    <VerticalStackLayout>
                        <Label Text="This is a modal page" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                    </VerticalStackLayout>
                </StackLayout>                
            </Frame>
        <ActivityIndicator 
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            Margin="0,16,0,0"
            IsVisible="True"
            IsRunning="True"/>
    </Grid>    
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: I must have missed how AbsoluteLayout does not work within a StackLayout. This solves it. Many thanks!

Comment: Well, it works within a StackLayout but differently from how you expected, I suppose. An AbsoluteLayout doesn't take up the entire space of the page, but the space of the container it is in and if that's a StackLayout, it's just one of several stacked items. You're welcome.